# C++ How to access this private member?

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a class called String with no ctor written, it has a private member

```
char s[maxlen+1];
```

which is not set until this method is called:

```
void assign (char const *st)
    {
        strcpy(s,st);
        len=strlen(st);
    }
```

In another class called Tick I have a member of type String

```
String name;
```

I want to write a copy constructor for the Tick class:

```
Tick::Tick( const Tick & obj )
{
        // Here are a bunch of primitive types copied
        // which I removed to keep it short
    name.assign(obj.name.s);
}
```

The String class does not have a return type for s, but I thought this should not be a problem as I have member name which is of type String and is able to access all members of an object of the same type. The compiler gives me the following error:

> error C2248: 'String::s' : cannot access private member declared in
>   class 'String'

Comment: Write a getter for `String::s`?

Comment: Yes, I know that would solve the problem. However this bugs me as I am missing out on understanding something about C++ here...

Comment: Your `assign` function is a terrible idea. It is far too easy for an accident to happen and to send in a string that is too big. The very utmost least thing you can do is use `strncpy`.

Comment: You must become one with the type.

Comment: `name.assign(obj.name.s);` What should this be please`?!? It's completely unclear what you'r asking about! [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please!!

Comment: You should design your class so that no other class needs access to `private` members. This is called *encapsulation*. Make all of your class's behaviour be defined by its `public` interface.  Relying on anybody who wants to copy your String to call some particular operations on it, is a dreadful idea

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ inside a copy ctor of class Tick, I want the String type member to be a copy of the member of the original object. name is the String type member and assign is a method of String. So I want to use it for accessing a private member of the name member of the original Tick object.

Comment: @user34920 Please [add additional information to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24234768/edit) rather than trying to clarify in comments! You're way off doing all of this right BTW ([see also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), and check what other's told you about encapsulation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to access `s` for this purpose. The default copy constructor for `Tick` will invoke the default copy constructor for `String` which will in turn copy `s` (assuming default copy constructors can be generated for both `Tick` and `String`).

If you need to write a custom copy constructor for `Tick` for other reasons, all you need to do to copy the `String` is:

```
name = obj.name;
```

That's what the default copy constructor for `Tick` would do.

So, if the default is sufficient, don't declare the copy constuctor for `Tick` at all. If it isn't, use the code above.

On a side note, an accessor to the underlying `char` array is useful when calling c-style APIs etc. Also, unless you *really* need a custom `String` class (*really? are you sure?*), use `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

Because s is a private member in class String, only functions inside class String can access it. You could make a get function inside String to retrieve the s `String::GetBuffer() const)`.  Or you could just copy the string class instead of s.

Comment: I tried to use name.assign() which is a function from within class String, as far as I understand it should be able to access private members. What do you mean copy the string class?

Comment: Why would the tick class bother to know anything about a raw char array. Instead, copy the String class with a copy function (kind off like a copy constructor). That assign function seems not a String::Assign() function to me, maybe you forgot to post that piece.

Comment: The assign function was written inside the class declaration so it has "normal" syntax, I did not notice this is not obvious outside context.

Comment: obj.name.s , that is the error. You are trying to acces a private member

Comment: That's true I somehow missed that! Thanks.